# Flutter plugin Android Multi module

Tags: android, flutter

I used as to create the flutter plugin project

After creation, it can run successfully

But when I opened the Android directory with as, I created a module a

Then in the project build.gradle add

```
implementation project(':a')
```

Go back to the Flutter project and run the prompt

> Project with path ':a' could not be found in project ':y_ demo'.
> setting.gradle have inclue ':a'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.